# How do you use a function to aggregate dataframe columns and sort them into quarters, based on the European dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, statistics

Hi I’m new to pandas and struggling with a challenging problem.

I have 2 dataframes:

Df1

```
Superhero ID    Superhero   City
212121          Spiderman   New york
364331          Ironman     New york
678523          Batman      Gotham
432432          Dr Strange  New york
665544          Thor        Asgard
123456          Superman    Metropolis
555555          Nightwing   Gotham
666666          Loki        Asgard
```

And

Df2

```
SID       Mission End date
665544    10/10/2020
665544    03/03/2021
212121    02/02/2021
665544    05/12/2020
212121    15/07/2021
123456    03/06/2021
666666    12/10/2021
```

I need to create a new df that summarizes how many heroes are in each city and in which quarter will their missions be complete. Also note the dates are written in the European format so (day/month/year).

I am able to summarize how many heroes are in each city with the line:

```
df_Count = pd.DataFrame(df1.City.value_counts().reset_index())
```

Which gives me :

```
 City       Count
New york     3
Gotham       2
Asgard       2
Metropolis   1
```

I need to add another column that lists if the hero will be free from missions certain quarters.

```
Quarter 1 – Apr, May, Jun
Quarter 2 – Jul, Aug, Sept
Quarter 3 – Oct, Nov, Dec
Quarter 4 – Jan, Feb, Mar
```

If the hero ID in Df2 does not have a mission end date, the count should increase by one. If they do have an end date and it’s separated into

So in the end it should look like this:

```
        City    Total Count    No. of heroes free in Q3    No. of heroes free in Q4   Free in Q1 2021+
    New york       3               2                           0                           1
    Gotham         2               2                           2                           0
    Asgard         2               1                           2                           0
    Metropolis     1               0                           0                           1
```

I think I need to use the python datetime library to get the current date time. Than create a custom function which I can than apply to each row using a lambda. Something similar to the below code:

```
    from datetime import date

today = date.today()
q1 = '05/04/2021'
q3 = '05/10/2020'
q4 = '05/01/2021'

count=0
def QuarterCount(Eid,AssignmentEnd )



    if df1['Superhero ID'] == df2['SID'] :

        if df2['Mission End date']<q3:
            ++count

             return count
          
        elif df2['Mission End date']>q3 && <q4:

            ++count

                return count
          
   elif df2['Mission End date']>q1:\

            ++count

                return count

     df['No. of heroes free in Q3'] = df1[].apply(lambda x(QuarterCount))
```

Please help me correct my syntax or logic or let me know if there is a better way to do this. Learning pandas is challenging but oddly fun. I'd appreciate any help you can provide :)

Comment: FYI, Pandas datetime tyoe columns have a direct quarter conversion [series.dt.quarter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html). You should be able to use the built-in to avoid `apply`

Comment: Thanks for responding. The only issue I'm having is applying the function to the df columns row by row. I'm not sure how I can do that without using apply()